# Laravel Elixir: require() not picking content of file while merging

Tags: php, laravel, gulp

So I am doing like this:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.scripts('app.js');
});
```

**app.js**

```
require('site');
```

when I run `gulp` it produces `app.js` in `/public` with line `require('site')` instead of putting content of it.

**Update**

Based on what was suggested I did:

`require('./site.js')` which produced following JS

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

require('./site');

},{"./site":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

alert('hi');

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is browserify:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.browserify('app.js');
});
```

In app.js you should get: `require('./site.js');`

Comment: ` Error: Cannot find module 'site' from '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/c/x/resources/assets/js'`

Comment: site.js is in this path?

Comment: I guess `require` is not working. Even `require("app")` is not working

Comment: You need to write absolute path like this require('./site.js');